# Where does Google Chrome store Usernames and Passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies, browser

I was wondering where does Google Chrome store Username and Passwords? Is it possible for someone to have access to these information?

Comment: Well - theoretically you could have access to anything, if you are skilled enough?

Comment: Have a look at this detailed answer: https://superuser.com/questions/146742/how-does-google-chrome-store-passwords

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q="OSCrypt::EncryptString"&type=cs